# .done() function not being run on returned promise from AJAX call when grabbing local JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to fetch a JSON file using an AJAX call but the `promise.done()` isn't being run despite readyState going up to 4. I get no errors so I have no idea why this is happening. The `getTemplate()` function works since I'm able to console log the promise, but from there nothing is working. I've tried removing the `dataType` from the AJAX call but it did nothing. Other than that I don't know what to change because I have used the same code for another project and it worked fine there. Does anyone have any idea on how I should proceed here?

**EDIT**: I have narrowed it down to it being the JSON file where the problem lies. What's wrong with my JSON file? http://jsfiddle.net/ym3z8aqh/2/

```
surveyView: {

    getTemplate: function() {

        var promise = $.ajax({
                        url: 'json/templateqa.json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json' //Removing this changes nothing,
                        async: false //Need false here so that readyState goes to 4
                      });

        return promise;
    },
    spawnQuestions: function() {

        var promise = surveyView.getTemplate();
            promise.done(function(data) {
                alert('working');
            });

        console.log(promise);
    }
}
```

Comment: `async: false` is definitely not needed here. I assume your JSON is not valid and thus cannot be parsed, or the URL is wrong. Pass an error callback as second argument to `done` and see what the issue is.

Comment: I checked if the path was correct and it was, so I guess there must be something with the file itself then. I'll check.

Comment: @FelixKling I get a "parsererror" when checking the textStatus and "SyntaxError: Unexpected token v {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token v"}" when checking the errorThrown. Can you take a look at this fiddle and see what might be wrong with the json file? It's my first time writing one so I might have done it completely wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/ym3z8aqh/

Comment: @FelixKling I think this is how it should be but it's still not working. http://jsfiddle.net/ym3z8aqh/1/

Comment: you don't put `var templateQA = ` in a JSON string. You just put the value (starting with `{`). See some [examples](http://json.org/example)

Comment: @abl I've done that if you look in the edit section, but it still comes up wrong.

Comment: Try http://jsonlint.com/ or a similar JSON validator. You've got apostrophes around all your strings instead of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you change your `JSON` to use quotation marks `"` instead of apostrophes `'`, you'll then notice that you have an invalid trailing comma in your `question_info`. Remove that and your resulting `JSON` will be valid:

```
{
    "templateQA": {
        "question_info": {
            "legend": "Fråga 1",
            "labelFor": "1",
            "inputID": "1",
            "inputName": "question"
        },
        "input_type": {
            "type_radio": {
                "labelFor": "radio",
                "labelText": "Kryssrutor",
                "inputID": "radio",
                "inputName": "type"
            },
            "type_textarea": {
                "labelFor": "text",
                "labelText": "Textfält",
                "inputID": "text",
                "inputName": "type"
            }
        },
        "radio_choices": {
            "first_choice": {
                "labelFor": "choice",
                "inputID": "choice",
                "inputName": "choicesquestion"
            },
            "second_choice": {
                "labelFor": "choice",
                "inputID": "choice",
                "inputName": "choicesquestion"
            },
            "third_choice": {
                "labelFor": "choice",
                "inputID": "choice",
                "inputName": "choicesquestion"
            },
            "fourth_choice": {
                "labelFor": "choice",
                "inputID": "choice",
                "inputName": "choicesquestion"
            },
            "fifth_choice": {
                "labelFor": "choice",
                "inputID": "choice",
                "inputName": "choicesquestion"
            }
        },
        "textarea": {
            "inputName": "textarea"
        }
    }
}
```